# How to disable or enable the chart visibility in BIRT

Tags: java, visibility, birt

I have a problem, I need to dynamically show the chart according to the user's selection with BIRT. Could anyone tell me how to do that with script? I have created the parameter for the selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to set the visibility property of the chart (or of a grid containing this chart) with an  expression using a parameter. This example hides the grid of a crosstab if the value of "View" report parameter equals to "charts".

[image]
However this is not the most efficient approach, because if we just turn off the visibility of a report element its datasets are still running silently.

Therefore the best way is to drop elements from *beforeFactory* script of the report. [This sample report](http://www.visioneo.org/cumulative-chart-flexible) makes use of both ways: the crosstab is hidden using *visibility* property, and the two charts are dropped in *beforeFactory*. Here is this beforeFactory script:

```
var design=reportContext.getDesignHandle();

if (params["View"].value=="cross"){
    design.findElement("gridCharts").drop();
}
```

Please notice the key point is to name report elements we need to drop.